# jQuery animated counter - decimal or whole numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to edit the following script to show the number with either decimals or whole numbers, depending on the attribute value. Currently, it shows all numbers with the decimal so 1.2 is ok but 90.0 is not.

```
jQuery('.counter-wrap .count').each(function () {
    var percent_hours = jQuery(this).attr('data-count');

    jQuery(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: percent_hours
        }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {                      
            jQuery(this).text(this.Counter.toFixed(1));
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yourbudweiser/nrsoh9t2/1/)

Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number itself if it is a decimal or not. If it is decimal you can add **.toFixed** function

```
if(Math.round(decimalOrNot) === decimalOrNot) {
    //decimalOrNot is not a decimal
}
else {
    //decimalOrNot is decimal
}
```

Comment: All the number are returning as decimal even though one is not a decimal..

Comment: Math.round(24.0) === 24.0 this returns true javascript does not uses .0

Comment: Still coming up as 90.0 though.. https://jsfiddle.net/yourbudweiser/nrsoh9t2/1/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use replace if .0...

```js
const n1 = 3.12345
const n2 = 5;

console.log(n1.toFixed(2).replace(/\.0+$/,''));
console.log(n2.toFixed(2).replace(/\.0+$/,''));
```

p.s with `toFixed(n)` method you can set how many numbers (n) after . you want

Answer (score 0):

You need some check if your counter is the whole number.

```js
step: function (now) {                      
   jQuery(this).text(
       Math.floor(this.Counter) === this.Counter
       ? this.Counter.toFixed(0)
       : this.Counter.toFixed(1));
}
```

Comment: All the number are returning as decimal even though one is not a decimal...

Comment: @Junky maybe try to replace `this.Counter` to `this.Counter.toFixed(0)`, so forcing whole numbers to have zero decimals?

Comment: replace which this.Counter?

Comment: Sorry, still not working. Please see my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yourbudweiser/nrsoh9t2/1/)